# iMac will not boot after Catalina auto-update

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imac, catalina, bootable-disk

I woke up the other morning to a prohibitory icon (circle with a line through it) on my iMac. I believe this was due to a failed Catalina update but I am not sure. I had it set to auto-update.

I am getting some strange results. I have booted into recovery mode and have a bootable flash drive as well as a 2T external drive that will also boot. I can not mount the main partition disk0s2. When I select that and click 'mount' it does nothing.

When I first boot into recovery mode then go to Disk Utility, there are a couple drives that are in RED. Then after I 'ignore' the fix that will delete all my data, they turn black (the normal text color).

I tried to continue the installation and I have gotten a few different issues tahat all amount to not being able to select my main drive.

The weirdest thing is that this is a 3T drive but in Disk Utility it is showing that it's 123.33GB.

[image: Disk Utility after running Verify Disk]

Here are the results of running:

`diskutil list`

[image: diskutil list]

and
`gpt -show /dev/disk0`

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone help me here? I am actually willing to hire someone even. I'm getting desperate and not 100% where to turn at this point.

Comment: The iMac has a Fusion drive of a 128GB and a 1, 2, or 3TB spinning HDD.  That second internal drive isn’t showing, leading me to believe it’s dead.    What model iMac is it specifically?

Comment: It's an iMac15,1. I added some hardware information above. What do you think?

Comment: In the future, just type out “27” 2015 iMac running Catalina 10.15.4.  Pictures can’t be searched and we have to go offsite to see what iMac15,1 refers to.  iMacs still come with a spinning drive, so I’m positive yours did as well.  The internal  3 TB drive has died (or the SATA controller on the logic board).  You’re going to have to open it up and swap that drive.  I’d put in an SSD for a huge performance boost

Comment: Will do, sorry about that and thanks for the shorthand there. Can you please give me some ideas on how I might possibly recover the data on this drive?

Comment: The problem that you’re having is that it isn’t even being seen by the system; you can’t fix what you can’t see.  I would still remove it so you could put it into an enclosure so you can attempt data recovery.

Comment: This happened during a Catalina auto update. I feel like that is one heck of a coincidence. I'm pretty bummed about this. Thank you for your help, I really do not know where else to turn.

Comment: It is a coincidence because no update disables your drive. You’re booting into Recovery so it’s not loading anything but a clean version of macOS

Comment: I forgot to add that I’m also running an iMac (spinning drive upgraded to SSD) and that this update hasn’t done anything detrimental (including hardware) to my system.  It was applied, I rebooted and all was and still is good.

Comment: Okay. I am going to have someone replace the 3T drive with a 2T SSD drive. Can you give me any specific guidance on how to recover the data from the dead drive? Literally anything you can tell me would be appreciated.